# Can I use sqlite database on WatchOS 3?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos

Is it possible to use sqlite database on WatchOS 3?

I shared a sqlite database with my Watch Extension App target (and my iPhone App target), but the query didn't work. I did import the library already - `#import "sqlite3.h"`. Anyone has the similar problem?

Since WatchOS 3 support Core Data, I think it should be able to support sqlite, too.

Answer (score 2):

I test with WatchOS 4 and SQLite works. I used a obj-c wrapped [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to access my SQLite database. The different between iOS and watchOS is the target should include "libsqlite3.tbd" instead of "libsqlite3.dylib".